# Jquery auto-complete displaying all data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a static json file which contains data in json format. Now, I have implemented auto-complete functionality using jquery plugin. My problem is that auto-complete displaying all the results including unnecessary ones. following my javascript code,

```
 $('input#searchBox').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/products_cache.json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {term: request.term},
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.products, function(item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.product,
                            label: item.product,
                            key: item.id
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minlength:2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#searchBox").val(ui.item.key);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
```

My json file contains data in the following format,

```
   {
"products": [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "product": "product1"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
        "product": "product2"
    },
    {
    "id":"3",
        "product": "product3"
    },
    {
    "id":"4",
        "product": "product4"
    },
    {
    "id":"5",
        "product": "product5"
    }
]
```

}

Ideally, when i am giving an input like ab, autocomplete should not provide any suggestion. How to filter out unwanted values?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ajax based jQuery. But I tried upon your code. If you got error, ignore my answer.

```
var ProductArray = [];
$('input#searchBox').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/products_cache.json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    ProductArray[key] = value.product; 
                });
                //  \\b show each match letter in each word of list
                //  ^ show each match letter in whole word of list
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                var a = $.grep(ProductArray, function(item, index) {
                    return matcher.test(item);
                });
                response(a);
            }
        });
    },
    minlength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#searchBox").val(ui.item.key);
    },
    open: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
});
```

This is how I use auto complete. My jQuery code (sample)...

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmanakumar/fjHKN/) for example

```
==== jQuery

    $(document).ready(function() {
        GetLocalityList();
    });

    function GetLocalityList() {
        var LocalityArray = ["win the day", "win the heart of", "win the heart of someone"];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: function(req, responseFn) {
                //  \\b show each match letter in each word of list
                //  ^ show each match letter in whole word of list
                var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term), "i");
                var a = $.grep(LocalityArray, function(item, index) {
                    return matcher.test(item);
                });
                responseFn(a);
            }
        });
    }

==== HTML

<body>
        <div>
            <label for="tags">
                Search : 
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="tags">
        </div>
</body>
```